# Figuring out RSA Encryption from 1 encrypted and decrypted message

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

Suppose that you have an encrypted message and a decrypted message (just one). M (the public key) and k (the exponent you raise each number to) are public. Does having one copy both version of a message give you enough information to decrypt other messages? I think the question boils down to finding the value of the euler phi of M which is not easy if you don't know its factorisation. I don't think there is a way to decrypt other messages but I'm not sure and am thankful for any help in advance.

Comment: The NSA will be knocking at your door shortly...

Comment: @user137500 The NSA doesn't need to knock at your door, it already knows all that it needs to! :P

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Any questions about it?

Answer (score 4):

Take any message you like. Encrypt it. You now have in your possession both an encrypted message, and the decrypted message. Does that help you to decrypt other messages?

Comment: Yup that's what I came up with.